# Sort index of array based on value

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I get the wrong index value when i am adding more than 10 values in my observable array, when i am trying to get current object like observableArray.indexOf(this). So i created new variable index value and generated like below example. But on enter i want to sort my observable array in descending order. So I want to do something like below example.

I have list of object with value like below

```
    1,20
    2,40
    3,10
    4,50
```

And I want result like

```
    3,20
    2,40
    4,10
    1,50
```

I want to sort my index value based on descending order of number in knockout observable.

Comment: I don't see any order in expected result...

Comment: @Rayon : see order of index value based on number

Comment: `3,2,4,1` can not be the order....

Comment: @Rayon : I want to change my value of index based on descending form of number

Comment: 3,2,4,1 are not in order but 50, 40, 20, 10 are in order, so I think what he wants is - first sort the values and then assign appropriate index.

Comment: @RomilGandhi Please provide some code sample of what you have tried so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Sort an mapped array based on value.
- Find the index of value based on the index from sorted array.

```js
var obj = [{
  index: 1,
  value: 20
}, {
  index: 2,
  value: 40
}, {
  index: 3,
  value: 10
}, {
  index: 4,
  value: 50
}];
var sortedArr = obj.map(function(el) {
  return el.value;
}).sort(function(a, b) {
  return b - a
});
var mapped = obj.map(function(el) {
  var index = sortedArr.indexOf(el.value) + 1;
  el.index = index;
  return el;
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(mapped,null,4));
```